# C# Onclick command not functioning

Tags: c#, code-behind, imagebutton

Below is an asp button that I need to run a C# command on the code behind page.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Retire" OnClick="this.retire" ImageUrl="/assets/images/ast/delete_32x32.png" AlternateText="~retire" ToolTip="Retire" runat="server" />
```

My C# code behind

```
public void retire(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["app_migrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Apps SET Migration_Phase = '-1' WHERE ID = @ID", connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", float.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]));
            }
            connection.Close();
            Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), false);
        }
    }
```

Do I need a different OnClick or am I missing something?

Comment: why have you put "this.retire" in onclick? It is just "retire".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
OnClick="this.retire"
```

to

```
OnClick="retire"
```

[**Server Event Handling in Web Forms Pages**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at2tetf6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Oh programming, it's just funny sometimes :)

Comment: @SonerGönül: Funny naming of the method, so it does exactly what it is supposed to do ;-)

Comment: What happened to question you asked a few minutes ago? I think your problem in that question is `ElementAt` method is zero based so it is ok to gives as a result `B`, IMO.